# How do I create a symbolic link to a directory with a space in it?

Tags: macos, command-line, symlink, alias, file

I was trying to create a symbolic link using the following command:

```
ln -s "~/Foo Bar/" Foo
```

... but it didn't work (i.e. when I go into finder and try double clicking it, it says that it's pointing to an invalid path and prompts me to delete the alias or fix it). I had to rename the folder to `FooBar` and then run the following command:

```
ln -s ~/FooBar/ Foo
```

How can I create the link without having to remove the space from the folder's name?

I'm looking for a way to do this in Terminal and not in Finder's UI.

Comment: While Gordon Davisson is right, you should be aware that aliases and symbolic links (symlinks) are different. `ln -s` makes symlinks. The Finder makes aliases. They are almost identical in practical, common use, but it's important to recognize that *they are different*. Symlinks point to a directory path, while aliases point to a file. If you have both pointing to the same file and you move the file to a different folder, then make a new file in the old folder, the alias will point to the moved original and the symlink will point to the new file.

Comment: @Cajun: thanks for the clarification. It's confusing that finder shows a symbolic link's "Kind" property as "Alias".

Comment: Tab completion is a wonderful thing too, if you were to do this: `ln -s ~/Foo<tab>` (where <tab> denotes the actual ⇥ (tab) key on your keyboard), if there is only one folder that starts with "Foo" in `~` then it will automatically expand the path to `~/Foo\ Bar/`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The quote marks are preventing `~` from being expanded to your home folder, so you need to either quote just the part with the space in it:

```
ln -s ~/"Foo Bar/" Foo
```

Note: exactly how much is quoted doesn't matter, as long as the space is in the quoted portion and the ~/ isn't. `~/Foo" "Bar/`, `~/"Foo Bar"/`, `~/Fo"o B"ar/` etc are all equivalent. Also, single- and double-quotes have the same effect on spaces (although they differ on other characters), so `~/'Foo Bar/'`, `~/Foo' 'Bar/` etc would also work.

You could also use an escape to prevent the space from being treated as a separator:

```
ln -s ~/Foo\ Bar/ Foo
```

Comment: You can serious quote JUST the space? That's awesome!

Comment: Or `"$HOME/Foo Bar/"`.

Comment: @wchargin That'll work. Note that unlike `~`, `$HOME` *should* be in double-quotes to prevent confusion if your home directory contains spaces or other weird characters. `"$HOME/Foo Bar/"` (as you suggest), `"$HOME"/Foo" "Bar/`, `"$HOME"/Foo\ Bar/`, etc will work.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it myself. I don't have a problem with a space in it:

```
    $ ln -s "/Users/joe/test/foo bar"/ linkToFoo_Bar
```

ls shows:  `$ linkToFoo_Bar -> /Users/joe/test/foo bar/`
and it works in terminal and finder without any problems.

Comment: You used a full path, not the `~` helper.